# Como chamar um fragment a partir de um botão da activity

Tags: android

Tenho tres fragments e uma activity. Nessa Activity tenho um botão, como faço para chamar um fragment a partir desse botão ? tenho um fragment que tem um botão partir desse botão preciso chamar outro fragment.

Eu sei chamar activities com o seguinte trecho de código:

```
Intent it = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
startActivity(it);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um **fragment** deve ser associado a uma **activity** para que este possa ser exibido. Para isso você deve definir um espaço dentro da **activity**(um container). Segue um exemplo.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
```

O espaço que o **Linear Layout** com id *container* ocupar será o espaço disponível para o **fragment**

Caso você use a biblioteca AppCompat você pode exibir um **fragment**

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new MenuFragment())
                .commit();
```

Onde *container* é o LinearLayout que eu defini e *MenuFragment* é o fragment que desejo exibir.

Caso você não use appcompat o código é semelhante segue abaixo:

```
Fragment fr = new Fragment();
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fr);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Essas chamadas de **fragment** pode ser feito tanto de um **fragment** para o outro como dentro de uma **activity**

Para fazer a chamada dentro de um fragment no click do botão basta apenas colocar o código dentro do `setOnClickListener` do botão.

Comment: Obg! Deu certo,

Comment: Caique, no meu caso eu tenho um LinearLayout e dentro dele um include onde estou colocando meu fragment. Tentei fazer o que você sugere acima, mas ao colocar o id ou da LinearLayout ou do include não reconhece dá a seguinte mensagem "Cannot resolve method 'add(int)' "

Answer (score -3):

exemplo

mBotaoCasdastrarPR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
getActivity().getSupportFagmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameLayout, new CadastrarFragment()).commit()
}
});